# row span on basis of same data in row using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to do row span on basis of same data using jquery. this is my fiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3havfcwv/1/)

Orignal Table

```
OUTPUT SHOULD BE:
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td  >1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" style="background-color:#F00;">1</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td rowspan="2"  style="background-color:#F00;">1</td>

    <td rowspan="2"  style="background-color:#F00;">1</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>131</td>
    <td>4155</td>
    <td>464</td>
    <td>46</td>
  </tr>
</table>
------------------------
```

row span on total number of same row data.if any cell contain different data then row should not be span.

Answer (score 0):

It's dependence on your data format, when you successful in control your data, you can use `.attr('rowspan', '2')` to add rowspan

Comment: instead of hard-code row span 2 ,can we dynamically given same data total rows

Comment: of course, as I said, it's dependence on your data format and what method did you control your data. `.attr('rowspan', numberOfRows)`